# ArgoCD & Traefik 2.x: How to configure argocd-server Deployment to run with TLS disabled (where to put --insecure flag)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik, kustomize, argocd

We have a setup with Traefik as the Ingress Controller / CRD and ArgoCD. We installed ArgoCD into [our EKS setup](https://github.com/jonashackt/tekton-argocd-eks) as described in [the Argo getting stared guide](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/):

```
kubectl create namespace argocd
kubectl apply -n argocd -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/stable/manifests/install.yaml
```

Now [as the docs state](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/ingress/#ingressroute-crd) the `IngressRoute` object to configure Traefik correctly looks like this:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: argocd-server
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
  routes:
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`argocd.tekton-argocd.de`)
      priority: 10
      services:
        - name: argocd-server
          port: 80
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`argocd.tekton-argocd.de`) && Headers(`Content-Type`, `application/grpc`)
      priority: 11
      services:
        - name: argocd-server
          port: 80
          scheme: h2c
  tls:
    certResolver: default
```

Right now [there's a bug in the docs](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/8950) - so be sure to remove the `options: {}` in order to let Traefik accept the configuration.

Traefik shows everything is fine in the dashboard:

[image]

But if we try to access the ArgoCD dashboard at https://argocd.tekton-argocd.de we get multiple `HTTP 307` redirects and can't access the dashboard in the end. You can see the redirects inside the developer tools:

[image]

Searching for a solution we already found [this issue](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/2953) where the problem is described:

> The problem is that by default Argo-CD handles TLS termination itself
> and always redirects HTTP requests to HTTPS. Combine that with an
> ingress controller that also handles TLS termination and always
> communicates with the backend service with HTTP and you get Argo-CD's
> server always responding with a redirects to HTTPS.

Also the solution is sketched:

> So one of the solutions would be to disable HTTPS on Argo-CD, which
> you can do by using the --insecure flag on argocd-server.

But how can we configure the `argocd-server` Deployment to add the `--insecure` flag to the argocd-server command - as it is also [stated inside the ArgoCD docs](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/ingress/#traefik-v22)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### **0. Why a declarative ArgoCD setup with Kustomize is a great way to configure custom parameters**

There are multiple options on how to configure ArgoCD. A great way is to use a declarative approach, which should be the default Kubernetes-style. Skimming the ArgoCD docs there's a [additional configuration section](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/server-commands/additional-configuration-method/#synopsis) where the possible flags of the ConfigMap `argocd-cmd-params-cm` can be found. The flags are described in [argocd-cmd-params-cm.yaml](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/argocd-cmd-params-cm.yaml). One of them is the flag `server.insecure`

```
## Server properties
# Run server without TLS
server.insecure: "false"
```

The `argocd-server` deployment which ships with https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/stable/manifests/install.yaml will use this parameter, if it is defined in the `argocd-cmd-params-cm` ConfigMap.

In order to declaratively configure the ArgoCD configuration, [the ArgoCD docs have a great section](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/declarative-setup/#manage-argo-cd-using-argo-cd) on how to do that with [Kustomize](https://kustomize.io/). In fact the ArgoCD team itself uses this approach to deploy their own ArgoCD instances - a live deployment is available here https://cd.apps.argoproj.io/ and the configuration used [can be found on GitHub](https://github.com/argoproj/argoproj-deployments/tree/master/argocd).

Adopting this to our use case, we need to switch our ArgoCD installation from simply using `kubectl apply -f` to a Kustomize-based installation. The ArgoCD docs also have [a section on how to do this](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/installation/#kustomize). Here are the brief steps:

### **1. Create a `argocd/installation` directory with a new file `kustomization.yaml`**

We slightly enhance the `kustomization.yaml` proposed in the docs:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
  - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/v2.3.3/manifests/install.yaml

## changes to config maps
patchesStrategicMerge:
  - argocd-cmd-params-cm-patch.yml

namespace: argocd
```

Since the docs state

> It is recommended to include the manifest as a remote resource and
> apply additional customizations using Kustomize patches.

we use the `patchesStrategicMerge` configuration key, which contains another new file we need to create called `argocd-cmd-params-cm-patch.yml`.

### **2. Create a new file `argocd-cmd-params-cm-patch.yml`**

This new file only contains the configuration we want to change inside the ConfigMap `argocd-cmd-params-cm`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: argocd-cmd-params-cm
data:
  server.insecure: "true"
```

### **3. Install ArgoCD using the Kustomization files & `kubectl apply -k`**

There's a separate `kustomize` CLI one can install e.g. via `brew install kustomize`. But as Kustomize is build into `kubectl` we only have to use `kubectl apply -k` and point that to our newly created `argocd/installation` directory like this. We just also need to make sure that the `argocd` namespace is created:

```
kubectl create namespace argocd --dry-run=client -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -    
kubectl apply -k argocd/installation
```

This will install ArgoCD and configure the `argocd-server` deployment to use the `--insecure` flag as needed to stop Argo from handling the TLS termination itself and giving that responsibility to Traefik. Now accessing https://argocd.tekton-argocd.de should open the ArgoCD dashboard as expected:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! this worked for me. However, the only hitch I ran into is that I needed to completely uninstall argocd before `kubectl apply -k directory-path` otherwise I was still getting redirect issues.

I uninstalled argocd with this command (note the version is specific to my installation):

`kubectl delete -n argocd -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/v2.4.0/manifests/install.yaml`

Comment: For me, it was enough to delete the "server" pod of ArgoCD (thus having it restart).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this traefik rule:

```yaml
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: argocd-server
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
  routes:
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`argocd.example.com`)
      priority: 10
      services:
        - name: argocd-server
          port: 80
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`argocd.example.com`) && Headers(`Content-Type`, `application/grpc`)
      priority: 11
      services:
        - name: argocd-server
          port: 80
          scheme: h2c
  tls: {}
```

It worked for me using traefik 2.6.3.

The troubleshot is at `tls: {}`.

Comment: I'm using Traefik in EKS. AWS NLB is just a pass-through but it throws "Internal server error".
argocli throws error as well

FATA[0004] rpc error: code = Unknown desc = POST https://argocd-dashboard.xxx.com:443/argocd/session.SessionService/Create failed with status code 500

My Traefik config - Intried inclusing certResolver as Default and my clusterissuer name, still the same result.

Comment: Same as in argocd documentation.
`
services:
- name: argocd-server
port: 80
- kind: Rule
match: Host(argocd-dashboard.xxx.com) && Headers(Content-Type, application/grpc)
priority: 11
services:
- name: argocd-server
port: 80
scheme: h2c
tls:
certResolver: traefik-letsencrypt-1 # Default or I removed this line as well, still 500 Internal error.
secretName: argocd-cert # same content as in traefik-cert
domains:
- main: argocd-dashboard.xxxx.com

`